# protoc-gen-javanano not found

Tags: android, gradle, protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm trying to use Protobuf in my Android application.
So to do that, I added the following lines in my gradle.build file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.5.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.google.protobuf"

sourceSets {
        main {
            proto {
                // In addition to the default 'src/main/proto'
                srcDir '../../../Libs/Protocol'
            }
        }
    }

protobuf {
    protoc {
        path = '/usr/local/bin/protoc'
    }
}
```

The thing is I get an error when gradle builds. It says that :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugProto'.
> protoc: stdout: . stderr: protoc-gen-javanano: program not found or is not executable
  --javanano_out: protoc-gen-javanano: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Can you help me with this issue ?
I have no idea of how to fix it.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: So you have application called protoc-gen-javanano in /usr/local/bin/protoc folder?

Comment: No, I'm just giving the path for protoc in gradle. But I added the line in order to fix my issue and it didn't so I assume that it's not the reason.

Comment: You assumption is wrong...  It is a path to protobuf binary

Comment: Ok so without this line in my build.gradle I still have this error. Have you any idea about a possible solution?

Comment: Oh come on read the doc... Use this solutions which download the binaries... I think right before this solution... Or this solution,  but change path to real path to protoc /protoc.exe (depends on platform Linux /windows)

Answer (score 1):

This means that the version of `protoc` you're using doesn't support javanano. An easy fix would be to use pre-compiled `protoc` on Maven Central by adding the following to your `build.gradle` (as suggested by the [documentation](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/tree/v0.7.4#locate-external-executables) of the protobuf gradle plugin):

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-alpha-3'
    }
}
```